# How to find the git hash for an npm release?

Tags: git, npm

I have released several package versions on npm. Now one version has introduced a regression and I'd like to identify the faulty commit. Users are reporting npm version numbers, but git only has commits (and doesn't have the release information).

How can I obtain the git commit from the npm version?

Comment: You're doing it backward. You should've put commit hash into the package during release process. Or create a tag for every release and put the tag into the package. Or create a tag the same as version string, thus you could know that package version 1.2.18 was released from the tag 1.2.18.

Comment: Nevertheless, I didn't... means there's no way to retrieve it?

Comment: Simple way? No. Hard way: compare the code from the package with every checked out revision looking for the smallest diff.

Comment: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/10/finding-specific-git-commit-at-point-in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding what git commit some code spawned from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898659/finding-what-git-commit-some-code-spawned-from)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+closest+commit

Answer (score 3):

Seems the short answer is: you can't do that. The npm package repository apparently doesn't reference to a git repo knowing it's commit but instead contains a copy of the code without a git commit reference.